Green transparent acrylic—effective in blocking red light noise of 840nm-LED IR floodlights?
I need to block the 'faint glow', which is to say red light noise, of an 850nm-LED IR floodlight.
Since green absorbs red, and acrylic transmits IR, natural approach seems to be to use a sheet of green transparent acrylic in front of the light. That correct?
(I'm aware there are 940nm-IR floodlights out there. For some reason, they are hardly available in Germany though.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is red light blocked? If yes, to what extent?

My question essentially is a question of principle. There are no further details yet. Sometimes questions are non-detailed, more about basic ideas, yet important.

For example, mathematics needed thousands of years to arrive at the principle of an algebraic field in its current form, including its intricacies.

The chemical engineers who chose (or invented) the dye (or dyes) that make the plastic look green to human eyes probably were not at all interested in whether or not those same dyes absorbed infrared light. The absorption spectrum of organic dyes can be quite complex, having many peaks and valleys.

I can state my question more precisely: The IR (nominal 850nm) source is not monochromatic, thus not exclusively emitting 850nm, but also noise as by-product, in particular visible noise. The latter is essentially red light of wavelength ≥ 700nm, low radiant flux, but relatively focused (LED). Which green acrylic may be able to i) absorb the red noise and ii) transmit IR ≥ 780nm ?

Maybe some moderator can move this very serious question to an appropriate StackExchange engineering forum.

You are very aggressive in your statements. I also do not think your question is well formulated. And I think you are being lazy: any person that would answer you, would simply google: "transmission spectrum green acrylic" or the sorts. However, we do not know which acrylic you are planning to buy. You should be the one knowing the product you are thinking about and try to see if there are any transmission spectra available. Ie, google "transmission spectrum XXX model acrylic". How should we know if the used green dye is transparent to 850nnm? Contact the manufacturer.

And no, your question is not very serious....

Two possibilities. 1. Use an 840 nm bandpass optical filter from one of the optical supply houses, e.g., Edmund, Thor Labs, etc. 2. Use a long pass optical filter at 800 nm or so. So the 840 nm would be transmitted and everything below 800 nm would be attenuated heavily. The green acrylic plastic might or might not work: it would attenuate the parasitic red emission, but might also have relatively poor transmittance at 840 nm. But it is inexpensive, so you could just try it.

It looks like your approach is correct.  The only real questions are whether the dye used also blocks IR, and whether the dye is effective enough at blocking your red glow.  My guess is that it won't block IR and that it will effectively block the red glow.  Faraday would have determined the answer empirically.  Here's a link to a study using a blue dye in different amounts.  Note the dip in the visible spectrum centered on red, and the ~90% transmission above 850nm.
https://scijournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pi.6082
